# How does a wormhole happen?

Tags: wormholes

Ive been watching a lot of Sci-fi movies and alot of them have to do with worm holes. I know they are real and I dont know how they form. I have been wondering how they form for a while.

Comment: sadly they are not known to be real, only theoretical concepts. At least the Lorentzian ones that can be used for interstellar transport are known to require negative energy in abundant quantities

Comment: *"I know they are real"* - how?  Knowledge is, at least, *justified* true belief.  Perhaps wormholes, in fact, exist but how do you *justify* your belief that they exist?  I assume your justification is not that you've seen a lot of sci-fi movies having to do with wormholes.

Comment: Take a neutron star in a shape of a donut and rotate it around its axis with the linear speed near the speed of light. Then try to jump through the hole, but don't expect to survive.